# Datatype problem in simple IF statement in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have a really weird problem and I am not 100% why the compiler is complaining. The code is as follows:

```
variable a : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
variable b : std_logic;
....
if (a = "100") AND (b) then
  -- do something
elsif (a = "011") OR (b) then
  -- do something else
```

I get the error message:

```
"AND can not have such operands in this context",
"OR can not have such operands in this context", respectively for the second IF statement.
```

Any idea why VHDL does not like this construction and if there is a workaround for that?

Answer (score 8):

VHDL is strongly typed - in a test context it expects booleans. Try `(b = '1')`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a vector with bit, one was it to change your code slightly to:

if (a = "100") then 
    if  (b) then
  -- do something
 end if
elsif (a = "011") then
   if (b) then
  -- do something else
  end if;
end if;